# Changing Python df values when string in row name matches column name after splitting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

My goal is to enter a 1 whenever a string in the 'SAD' column matches a column name, and 0 otherwise.

So we have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SAD': ['Game;Pool;Read;lol','Game;Read'], 'Game':[0,0], 'Pool': [0, 0], 'Read':[0, 0], 'Drink' : [0, 0]})
```

I have tried this: Splitting then assigning:

```
l= df["SAD"].apply(lambda x: x.split(";"))

for i in l:
   for x in i:
     if x in df.columns:
        df[x]=1
print(df)
```

However this replaced the entire dataframe with 1 at the first sight of a string that matches:

```
                        SAD  Game  Pool  Read  Drink
0        Game;Pool;Read;lol     1     1     1      0
1                 Game;Read     1     1     1      0
```

The desired output would be:

```
                            SAD  Game  Pool  Read  Drink
    0        Game;Pool;Read;lol     1     1     1      0
    1                 Game;Read     1     0     1      0
```

Comment: Can you copy your question and ask it again? it says that its a duplicate question and it refers to another question, for that reason im only able to comment on your question and not able to answer it. I've made a script that gets your desired result. Please ask the question again as a seperate question and comment the link down here and i'll send you the script. Im not able to comment the script because there are to many characters

Comment: I just did, would love your input. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008397/python-changing-values-in-dataframe-after-splitting

Comment: Posted my code!